# Unable to install a package in Python (pip)

Tags: python-3.x, pip, installation

The host is an isolated one and doesn't have internet connection. I have downloaded all the necessary packages and installed them using pip. But while doing the last one I am getting below error. Can anyone help me in this?

```
ERROR: No matching distribution found for setuptools>=40.8.0 while I have setuptools 45.2.0
installed already.
```

```
C:\Annada\Python\package>pip list|findstr setuptools
setuptools       45.2.0

C:\Annada\Python\package>pip install grip_tools-0.1.9.tar.gz
Processing c:\annada\python\package\grip_tools-0.1.9.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\prasa502\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\prasa502\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\prasa502\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-p4z1oajg\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel
       cwd: None
  Complete output (7 lines):
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x039EAEB0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/setuptools/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x039EA730>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/setuptools/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x039EA6B8>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/setuptools/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x039EAFE8>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/setuptools/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x039EAE38>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/setuptools/
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools>=40.8.0 (from versions: none)
  ERROR: No matching distribution found for setuptools>=40.8.0
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\prasa502\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\prasa502\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\prasa502\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-p4z1oajg\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: try upgrading pip. `pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: What is `grip_tools`? Where can we see its source code?

Comment: Do you ahve 32 bit python on purpose?

Comment: @PedroRodrigues : I will try to upgrade and will let you know.

Comment: @phd : grip_tools is a package developed by our organization. it's is not public. So as of now no one can see the package.

Comment: @FlyingTeller : To be absolutely frank, I am very new to Python. I download from https://www.python.org/downloads/ page which is visible. But after you just pointed out, I did some browsing inside the website and found a 64 bit also exists. I think I have to remove this 32 bit and install 64 bit.